# Meaning of "has executed this Agreement as to Proprietary Rights this … day of …" on a job offer

Tags: job-offer

I just recently received a job offer (yay) but I'm unsure what should be filled in the blank lines of this part from my job offer.

Comment: A simple solution is to call them and ask what this means.

Comment: Others have answered with what is expected in the form. I'm just a bit concerned about exactly what "proprietary rights" you are assigning them. I I'm not used to seeing an intellectual property rights agreement built into the offer. If in any doubt, it may be worth paying a lawyer to sanity check that language.

Comment: @keshlam: They are very, very common in jobs where creativity is required, such as the IT sector. The exact rights are enumerated in "this Agreement". The "as to Proprietary right" clause there exists so lawyers can later claim that you knowingly signed an agreement about these rights

Comment: My problem isn't the ip agreement -- it's just that I hadn't seen one signed quite this early in the process. If that's really now the norm, OK.

Comment: You might want to read the section before this carefully: Proprietary Rights  might be something that can effect the rest of your life...

Comment: The implication of consider the snippet was raised by me in the very first comment and deleted by moderator.

Comment: The phrase Propietary Rights seems to just be a reference to the rest of the agreed terms. You've got to review the terms you are agreeing to. The phrase "Proprietary Rights" is not a problem in itself.

Comment: "Dear prospective employer, is the offer letter available in English, or only in Legalese?"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If signing today I would put:

Rights this **3rd** day of **March**, 201**6**

Comment: @jimm101: I've signed quite a few documents where that line just means you are signing it, not that it requires a notary.

Comment: This is correct. People are misreading "In witness whereof"; it merely means that the signature is the employee's affirmation of agreement to the terms. If they required it to be notarized there would be more words there, something like "________, employee, appeared before me and acknowledged that his signature on this document ...".

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**: For anyone like me who thought "in witness whereof" means a separate person needs to witness the document, that is not the case.  It is just a legal archaism that is almost meaningless. I based my answer on [an unreliable webpage](http://www.ask.com/government-politics/phrase-witness-whereof-mean-930f5f38fff0e213). Thanks to Pete for pointing out my error.

<strike>I'm not sure, but I think you should not fill in those lines. "IN WITNESS WHEREOF" means you need to have a witness sign this section, perhaps a notary public with a seal. The witness will fill in the date when they sign.</strike>

That being said, if <strike>your employer hasn't said anything about needing a witness for this contract</strike> you aren't sure how to fill out something in your employment contract, ask them what to do.

Comment: No, "witness" here has an old, funky meaning. Webster's online gives this definition: "something serving as evidence or proof". That is, the signature is affirming that the signee agreed to whatever is in the contract.

Comment: The second paragraph of this is better advice "ask them what to do" if you don't know.